# SignedXml not working right when verifying a signature

Tags: .net, casting, verify, xml-dsig, signedxml

This [this Microsoft's example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx) of using **SignedXml** class to verify a signature and it didn't work for me (in Visual Studio 2013 with .NET version 4.0) due to casting *XmlNode* to *XmlElement* in the code:

```
Boolean VerifyDetachedSignature( String^ XmlSigFileName )
{

   // Create a new XML document.
   XmlDocument^ xmlDocument = gcnew XmlDocument;

   // Load the passed XML file into the document.
   xmlDocument->Load( XmlSigFileName );

   // Create a new SignedXMl object.
   SignedXml^ signedXml = gcnew SignedXml;

   // Find the "Signature" node and create a new 
   // XmlNodeList object.
   XmlNodeList^ nodeList = xmlDocument->GetElementsByTagName( "Signature" );

   // Load the signature node.
   signedXml->LoadXml( safe_cast<XmlElement^>(nodeList->Item( 0 )) );

   // Check the signature and return the result. 
   return signedXml->CheckSignature();
}
```

By "didn't work" I mean that it didn't throw any exceptions even though I had removed referenced files (those that are referred to in the *References* in *Signed XML* file). That means it just *didn't check* them.

But when I initialized *signedXml* this way:

```
   SignedXml^ signedXml = gcnew SignedXml(xmlDococument);
   signedXml->LoadXml(xmlDococument->DocumentElement);

   //xmlDococument->DocumentElement is an XmlElement
```

it worked flawlessly both throwing exceptions when referenced files not found and returning a "true" value (because the signature's correct) when all referenced files found.

That means **something wrong happens when casting XmlNode to XmlElement**, even though (even though it does return exactly the very node that I need). I even tried writing it with XmlWriter and got what I needed.

**The problem** is that I need to do it the **cast XmlNode to XmlElement** way because the XML file I'm working with has a **Signature** element further down the tree (that is, it's not the root node) and I need to use *SelectSingleNode* or *GetItemByTagName*. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: No, but I firured out a workaround. If I recall correctly, I saved the node to a file, then loaded that file as XmlDocument and then performed CheckSignature.